# lograr que un div interno sea siempre 10px mas pequeño que su contenedor

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Bien, tengo un `div` con un alto establecido (300px) y un `width` flexible... Ahora, dentro de este, existe otro `div`, llamado **caja** este `div` lo uso para crear como un borde, pero dentro de la caja...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo asi... intenté ponerle `margin`, pero no funciona. Es como que tengo que hacer una caja interna mas chiquita. Si el tamaño del contenedor fuese estatico seria facil, solo le resto `5px` a cada lado y ya, pero como el `width` es flexible, pues no puedo.

Básicamente necesito un `div` interno que tenga el mismo `width -10px`

Lo del `HoverBox` es para un efecto `hover`, puedes ignorarlo, igual ese `div` en el `css` ocupa el 100% del contenedor.

```css
.general-container {
  .... display: flex ....
}

.contenedor {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-size: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 10px;
}

.Caja {
  position: absolute;
  width: 96%;
  height: 92%;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(247, 9, 9, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<section class="general-info">
  <a href="">
    <div class=" image image1">
      <div class="hoverBox" id="hoverBox">
        <div class="Caja">
          <div class="texto">Eran sus flores favoritas</div>
          <div class="textoOculto">Porque los girasoles siempre le encantaron.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="image image2">
      <div class="hoverBox" id="hoverBox">
        <div class="Caja">
          <div class="texto">Paseos en el bosque</div>
          <div class="textoOculto">Para relajar el alma y mantenerte en armonía.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</section>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es sencillo de resolver, si pasas el HTML puedo armarte un ejemplo, seria bueno entender como tienes estructurado el HTML, técnicamente no seria necesario que la segunda div sea absolute y es esto lo que te está generando el problema con los margenes..

Comment: Claro, ya mismo te lo paso

Comment: Si no entiendes el HTML porque tiene algunas cosas extra, porfa puedes mostrarmelo con dos divs o con `before-after` y yo me encargo de aplicarlo a mi caso

Comment: Claro, en unos minutos te lo armo con y te lo paso, sería ideal hacerlo por before o after porque la línea es puramente estético...

Comment: Genial, muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que al usar un position **absolute** se sitúa en una posición específica con respecto a su primer ancestro no estático, en este lugar el que definiste como **relative**. Si al de adentro le decimos que ocupará un 100% y le aplicamos márgenes, lo que pasa es que se va para afuera del lado derecho e inferior, por otro lado si usas porcentajes como 96% siempre actuará diferente.
Entonces puedes hacerlos de varias maneras, dejo 2 a continuación, una es con un div adentro de otro que ocupe el 100% y jugar con margin y padding.
La otra es generarlo por css con after o before, ponerlo con posición absoluta en top 10px y left 10px y luego darle un 100% de ancho y alto y restarle 20px (los 10 que se corre de la izquierda + los 10 que quedarían hacia adentro de la derecha)

Armé 2 ejemplos que te servirán de referencia, en ambos casos agregué un contenedor y dejé centrado el div con el cuadro adentro, les puse un texto abajo a la izquierda como en tu ejemplo y les agregué una imagen de fondo con una url externa para que puedas probar el código tal cual está.

---

**Ejemplo 1: Con un div dentro de otro.**

```css
.contenedor {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.div1 {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/14/13/23/ocean-3605547__340.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 60%;
  max-height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 400px;
  padding: 10px 11px 12px 10px;
}

.div2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid rgb(230, 116, 23);
}

.div2 h2 {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="div1">
      <div class="div2">
        <h2>Eran sus flores favoritas..</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

**Ejemplo 2: Con un único div y otro en un after.**

```css
.div1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/14/13/23/ocean-3605547__340.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 60%;
  max-height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.div1 h2 {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
}

.div1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 24px);
  height: calc(100% - 24px);
  border: 2px solid rgb(209, 112, 26);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="div1">
      <h2>Eran sus flores favoritas</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Joder, veo la respuesta y me siento un poco tonto porque era realmente sencillo. Muchas gracias Luis.

Comment: Me alegra haber podido ayudar, quedo a las órdenes!